# Training Set Balancing Strategies

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

If you had a training set containing instances for various classes and it was highly imbalanced. What strategy would you use to balance it?

Information about real-world population: 7 classes whereof the smallest accounts for 5%.

Information about training set: frequencies differ largely from the populations frequencies.

Here are two options:

- Bias it to the populations class frequencies.
- Bias it to a uniform distribution.

With biasing i intend something like SMOTE or Cost-Sensitive Classification.

I am insecure which strategy to follow. I am also open for other suggestions. How would you evaluate the success of the strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, for training you have two options. Either to balance your data set (works if you have very large amount of data and/or small number of features, so that throwing away some samples won't affect learning), or use different weights for different classes, according to their frequencies. The latter is typically straightforward to do, but depends on the method and library you choose.

Once you have your classifier trained (with some prior on your training set), you can easily update the prediction probabilities if your priors change (different frequencies in training and population). There is an excellent overview how to replace the prior information, that explains it better than I could in a short post. Take a look at [Combining probabilities](http://www.mpia-hd.mpg.de/Gaia/publications/probcomb_TN.pdf), Section 3 (Replacing prior information).

Comment: That is not really what i wanted to know. I'm asking myself whether the optimal training set should represent a distribution as the pouplation or whether it should be biased to a uniform distribution.

Comment: I think I understood your question. You *should* account for the imbalance: so either train on balanced if you have sufficient data, or unbalanced ones *with bigger weights for smaller classes*. Both approaches can work fine. 

If you use a balanced set, then update the predictions using the population frequency prior.

Comment: Thank you for insisting! I understood your answer now. Basically what you are saying is, that i should first balance the training set and then update the model with the prior probabilities. Thanks!